# r looping through a data.frame to run same regression with differing DVs and weights

Tags: r, lm

Hi I'm having trouble getting lm in lapply to loop through different DVs for which I have pre-determined corresponding weight columns in my data.frame.

Here's a working example:

```
require(dplyr)


df <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(
  vars(mpg:drat),
  funs(wt=rnorm(n()))
  )
dvs <- names(select(df,mpg:drat))
res <- list()
res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  lm(formula,df)
})
```

But this returns "object 'mpg_wt' not found"

```
res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  weightvars <- paste0(x,"_wt")
  lm(formula,weights=as.formula(weightvars),df)
})
```

and this returns "variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')"

```
res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  weightvars <- paste0(x,"_wt")
  lm(formula,weights=eval(weightvars),df)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parse and pass `weightvars` as value of `text`.

I hope this helps:

```
res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  weightvars <- paste0(x,"_wt")
  lm(formula,weights=eval(parse(text=weightvars)),df)
})
```

or use `as.name` function inside `eval` as shown below:

```
res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  weightvars <- paste0(x,"_wt")
  lm(formula,weights=eval(as.name(weightvars)),data=df)
})
```

Comment: thanks! strangely neither of these solutions work with felm() from the lfe package, both returning "object 'mpg_wt' not found"

Comment: @JohnClegg thanks for the comment. I have added `df` to make an explicit call as shown:  `res <- lapply(dvs, function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(x," ~ wt + qsec + as.factor(vs)"))
  weightvars <- paste0("df$", x,"_wt")
  felm(formula,weights=eval(parse(text=weightvars)),df)
})`